# FieldError at /students/delete_gr/234/

Tags: python, django

> FieldError at /students/delete_gr/234/

I am trying to delete `gr`. It's not working, giving an error:

> Cannot resolve keyword `id` into field. Choices are: address, area_code, area_code_id, class_register, classes_A, classes_A_id, classes_C, classes_C_id, date_birth, fee, first_name, gardian, gender, gr_no, last_name, sections_A, sections_A_id, sections_C, sections_C_id, status

**views.py**

```
def delete_gr(request, pk):

gr_register.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
gr = gr_register.objects.all()

context = {
    'gr' : gr 
}
return render(request, 'students/home.html', context)
```

**viewdata.html**

```
{% extends 'authenticate/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
   <h2 class="text-center" style="font-family:sans-serif;">GR-Record</h2>
    <hr/>
   <div class="addgr text-right" style="margin-bottom: -50px;">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" type="submit"><a href="{% url 'addgrregister' %}">Add-GR Register</a></button>
  </div>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-2">
        <input 
        class="form-control mr-sm-2" 
        type="search" 
        placeholder="Search" 
        aria-label="Search"
        name="search"
        value="{{search_term}}">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      <br/>
  <div class="table-responsive ">
  <table class="table table-hover table-dark table-bordered table-sm">
      <caption>List of GR-students</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>GR No</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Date Of Birth</th>
      <th>Class Of Admission</th>
      <th>Section Of Admission</th>
      <th>Gender</th>
      <th>Current Class</th>
      <th>Current Section</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Area Code</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for gr in gr %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{gr.gr_no}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.date_birth}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.classes_A}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.sections_A}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.gender}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.classes_C}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.sections_C}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.address}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.area_code}}</td>
        <td>{{gr.status}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'editgr' gr.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button"> Edit</a><br/>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_gr' gr.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button"> Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {%endfor%}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
      <br/><br/>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please add models in the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because there is no field named as `id` in `gr_register` model.

> Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field.

If there is no primary key explicitly defined for a model then only `id` will be created automatically for model.

Use this to query to get gr_register queryset.

```
gr_register.objects.filter(pk=pk).delete()
```